# Teradata 15 Failure 5678 The user is not authorized to assign the default role

Tags: teradata, database-administration

I can execute the following using DBC, but failed when U used SYSDBA user.  I thought I have granted all rights to SYSDBA, but I must missed this one.

```
CREATE USER "zz_01" 
  FROM ALL_USERS AS
PASSWORD="s#rMdfdgd1",
PERMANENT = 0,
SPOOL = 0,
TEMPORARY = 0,
COLLATION = HOST,
ACCOUNT = 'sysdba',
NO FALLBACK,
NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
NO AFTER JOURNAL,
TIME ZONE = NULL,
DATEFORM = NULL,
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET LATIN,
DEFAULT ROLE = "SL-TERADATA-TEST",
PROFILE = PROFILE_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT;
```

*** Failure 5678 The user is not authorized to assign the default role 'SL-
 TERADATA-TEST'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `ADMIN OPTON`:

```
GRANT "SL-TERADATA-TEST" TO SYSDBA WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

Maybe you should allow SYSDBA to create roles, too, then he will automatically get that right for all new roles:

```
GRANT ROLE TO SYSDBA;
```

Comment: It did not work for all roles.  It only worked if I GRANT "SL-TERADATA-TEST" TO SYSDBA WITH ADMIN OPTION; After I revoke the grant statement to sysdba, SYSDBA cannot assign the default role again.

Comment: @dave: As I wrote, this only works for **new** roles created **after** the GRANT. If you don't want to assign the ROLE right to SYSDBA permanently you must  GRANT the ADMIN OPTION for each role separately.

Comment: I did grant role to sysdba. But it did not make a difference.  I got the same error when using sysdba to assign roles.  Sysdba is my DBA user and I want to use it pretty much for all DBA work I do everyday.  Thanks again for taking time to reply!!

Comment: @dave: you're right, only DBC is automatically added as member and granted the ADMIN option when other users create roles. So you must either create new roles using SYSDBA or grant him the admin option after every new role...

Comment: Got it.  I will simply change my create user script to use the grant role to user option, instead of using the default role option.  Many thinks.